# Expected arc length with fixed point versus without

Tags: probability, expected-value

Given a circle of circumfence $1$ and on that circle, $n$ uniformly randomly placed points $X_1, \ldots, X_n$. We can identify each point $X_i$ with some real value in the interval $[0, 1)$, i.e., the $X_i$ are chosen from $U(0,1)$. Adjacent points on the circle form arcs. I'm confused about the expected lengths of those $n$ arcs.

On the one hand, the problem is completely symmetric, so the expected lengths of all arcs should be equal, thus $1/n$. None of the arcs should be "special".

On the other hand, one of the points is the smallest value and one is the largest. The expected value of the minimum is $1/(n+1)$ and the expected value of the maximum is $n/(n+1)$. This means that the expected length of the arc crossing $0$ is $2/(n+1)$, but for all other arcs $1/(n+1)$. This makes the 0-crossing arc "special".

I'm having trouble reconsiling those to answers. Help please?

Comment: Your trouble with reconciling is that the your interval calculation is wrong. While choosing $n$ points from the interval will split it into $n+1$ sub-intervals, there is no reason to expect that the top and bottom intervals will be the same size as the average of the middle intervals.

Comment: @PaulSinclair In which place do you think the calculation is wrong? Do you contend that $E[min(X_1, ..., X_n)] = 1/(n+1)$ and $E[max(X_1,...,X_n)] = n/(n+1)$? Assuming that's correct, it means that the bottom interval and top interval both have expected length $1/(n+1)$, does it not? That leaves $(n-1)/(n+1)$ spread over the remaining $n-1$ intervals, so I'm assuming them to have expected size $1/(n+1)$ too, concluding that all $n+1$ intervals are expected to have the same size.

Comment: Yes, as I said in my first comment, I exactly contend that those two expectations are wrong.

Comment: @PaulSinclair These two expectations follow directly from minimum and maximum of independent random variables. For the maximum $M=max(X_1,...,X_n)$, the CDF is $F_M(x)=x^n$, so for $E(M)$ we have to integrate $x * n * x^{n-1}$ over $[0,1]$ which is $n/(n+1)$. The minimum $N$ is similar with $F_N(x)=1-(x-1)^n$ as CDF and we get $E(N)=1/(n+1)$ for the integral.

Comment: You are of course correct that my thinking was too shallow on this. The expectations are as you say. Question: what expected interval do you calculate between $0.5$ and the highest value lower than it? And between $0.5$ and the lowest value higher than it?

Comment: @PaulSinclair For the interval between 0.5 and the lowest value higher than it, it could be that all values $X_i$ are lower than 0.5. In that case, let's assume we want to "wrap around" by taking 0.5 plus the smallest of the $X_i$ instead, which matches the setting of the circle. I would again expect length $1/(n+1)$ here, since there is a bijection between this and the original question by mapping each point $x$ to $x-0.5$ with "wrap around", i.e., we bring $x$ to $x-0.5+1$ if $x<0.5$. Your other question is symmetric. And this argument goes for any $p$, not just $0.5$. Hm.

Comment: In fact, the special case of $n=2$ is already troubling. On the one hand, the two intervals between two points $A$ and $B$ independently and uniformly randomly chosen on the circle are expected to have length $1/2$, i.e., $E[AtoB] = E[BtoA]=1/2$ with $AtoB = B-A$ if $A<B$ and $AtoB=B-A+1$ otherwise. On the other hand, the interval $[0,1]$ is split into 3 intervals between values $0$, $min(A, B)$, $max(A, B)$ and $1$ which are all expected to be equally long. How can that be?!

Comment: But here is the point, The expected length between $A$ and $B$ is $1/3$, but the the expected length to a fixed point is the same. This oddity between the circle and the interval actually shows up in the interval itself without respect to the circle. So the problem is not in circle vs interval, but in our intuition about intervals to fixed points vs random points.